# remove or hide root node in hierarchical TreeView

Tags: wpf, treeview, hide, root, hierarchy

I have a TreeView like so:

```
<TreeView Name="tvObjects" Padding="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="2">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,3" ContextMenu="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NodeTypeToContextMenuConverter}}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverter}}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Padding="4,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Its bound like so:

```
tvObjects.Items.Clear();
var root = new Node("SQLite", NodeType.SQLite);
// add db nodes, with sub nodes
tvObjects.Items.Add(root);
```

I would like to not show the root node, but only its children. Currently it looks like:

[image]

I want it to look like:

[image]

Note it has to be hierarchical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the root node, simply ***don't add it in Items collection***.
Add db nodes directly to Items collection:

```
var node = new Node("main", NodeType.Whatever);
// add sub nodes.
tvObjects.Items.Add(node);

var anotherNode = new Node("chin ook", NodeType.Whatever);
// add sub nodes.
tvObjects.Items.Add(anotherNode);
```

Comment: Thanks for stating the obvious. For some reason after reading some I thought I could not get away without having a single root in hierarchical data.